# Bulk Insert Random Data From Table

Tags: bulkinsert

I want insert random data value from my table in my bulk insert like that.

```
 INSERT INTO insertedtable
   SELECT s.a,
          s.b,
          s.c,
          s.d,
          s.e,
          (SELECT *
             FROM (SELECT pruchasecode
                     FROM pruchtable
                    ORDER BY dbms_random.value)
            WHERE rownum < 2)

     FROM seltable s
```

But it insert one value.
how can i insert random value each row in bulk insert statement.

I thought loop but execution cost is low.

Thanks.

Comment: What DBMS do you use?

Comment: it getting random data from pruchtable

Comment: Yes, i get that! But it's quite important to know which database management system (DBMS) you use, e.g. SQL Server or Oracle, since the differences in the sql code are quite significant.